# List of CPU models and their expected idle CPU temperature?

Tags: cooling

Is there a list of CPU models and their expected idle CPU temperature?

**Background**

One of my CPUs had become sluggish: It would run at full speed for a very short time before throttling down.

By happy coincidence I had measured its idle temperature when it was bought. It was around 40 C. Now the idle temperature was around 80 C. So I figured this could be a cooling problem.

And I was right: The fan was full of dust, and the cooling paste had solidified to the consistency of rubber. After cleaning the fan and replacing the cooling paste, the idle temperature fell to around 40 C again. And the CPU now happily ran at full speed for extended periods of time. Problem solved.

Now I am curious whether I might have other machines with bad cooling, and I really do not want to replace cooling paste on all CPUs "just to be safe". I would much rather compare the current idle temperatures to the expected idle temperature. But given that the CPU in my phone has a much lower idle temperature than the CPUs in my compute machines, I reckon the expected idle temperature depends on the CPU model.

So is there a reference to which I can compare the idle temperatures of my CPUs?

Comment: to honestly i think no, because the same cpu on 2 os will have different temps. i. e. my old celeron laptop under windows heated my coffee well enough, under linux it was idling with the lowest speed ehen doing nothing and i needed to speed up my xup to drink instead windows where its been running between 50-70% min speed

Answer (score 1):

Temperatures to some extent depend on the heat transfer properties of the system. Hot phones in pockets become uncomfortable very quickly. Many big systems on the Top 500 list are water cooled to achieve crazy power density, but the thermals are always a limiting factor.

Because of the huge variation in different environments, I doubt you will get a comprehensive list of temperatures for all CPUs. Maximum power dissipation of a CPU, assurances that it will adapt its performance to the thermals, sure. And from the server specs, maximum operating and optimal air flow temperatures. But this doesn't obviously correlate with on core temperatures, which can safely go quite high before throttling back or shutting down completely.

You noticed this as a performance problem. In the absence of good data like fan status or thermometers that tell you what they read, find problem hardware that throttles back at high CPU. Know the performance of your typical hosts, and find the outliers. In your performance issue checklist, at some point try different hardware by failing over or trying one of your spares. Gives time to blow out the dust and fix heatsinks. At worst, performance wasn't the fault of cooling, but you tested your response to hardware failures.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a list of CPU models and their expected idle CPU temperature?

No, because there is no single "expected idle temperature" for a CPU. The efficiency of the CPU's cooling solution and the ambient air temperature will both have a significant effect on the idle temperature.

There are a number of additional complicating factors in a laptop -- in particular, other components (like the southbridge and GPU) often share the heatsink with the CPU, and there may be other significant heat-generating components present, like DC-DC converters or the battery.

This all being said -- from a practical standpoint, an easy way to judge the "health" of a laptop's cooling is to listen to the fan. If it's constantly running at maximum speed and making a lot of noise, that's a sign that there may be a problem.